# Function within Worker/Child instance does not return, freezes program

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I am using the multiprocessing module in python. Here is a sample of the code I am using:

```
import multiprocessing as mp


def function(fun_var1, fun_var2):
    b = fun_var1 + fun_var2
    # and more computationally intensive stuff happens here
    return b
    # my program freezes after the return command


class Worker(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self, queue_obj, func_var1, func_var2):
         mp.Process.__init__(self)
         self.queue_obj = queue_obj
         self.func_var1 = func_var1
         self.func_var2 = func_var2


    def run(self):
         self.var = function( self.func_var1, self.func_var2 )
         self.queue_obj.put(self.var)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mp.freeze_support()

    queue_list = []
    processes = []
    result = []

    for i in range(2):
        queue_list.append(mp.Queue())
        processes.append( Worker(queue_list[i], i, var1, var2 )
        processes[i].start()

    for i in range(2):
        processes[i].join()
        result.append(queue_list[i].get())
```

During runtime of the program two instances of the worker class are generated which work simultaneously. One instance finishes after about 2 minutes and the other would take about 7 minutes. The first instance returns its results fine. However, the second instance freezes the program when the function() that is called within the run() method returns its value. No error is being thrown, the program just does not continue to execute. The console also indicates that it is busy but not displaying the >>> prompt. I am completely clueless why this behavior occurs. The same code works fine for slightly different inputs in the two Worker instances. The only difference I can make out is that the work loads are more equal when it executes correctly. Could the time difference cause trouble? Does anyone have experience with this kind of behavior? Also note that if I run a serial setup of the program in which function() is just called twice by the main program, the code executes flawlessly. Could there be some timeout involved in the worker instance that makes it impossible for function() to return its value to the Worker instance? The return value of function() is actually a list that is fairly small. It contains about 100 float values.

Any suggestions are welcomed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of an educated guess without actually seeing what's going on in worker, but is it possible that your child has put items into the `Queue` that haven't been consumed? The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues) has a warning about this:

> Warning
>
> As mentioned above, if a child process has put items on a queue (and
>   it has not used JoinableQueue.cancel_join_thread), then that process
>   will not terminate until all buffered items have been flushed to the
>   pipe.
>
> **This means that if you try joining that process you may get a deadlock
>   unless you are sure that all items which have been put on the queue
>   have been consumed. Similarly, if the child process is non-daemonic
>   then the parent process may hang on exit when it tries to join all its
>   non-daemonic children.**
>
> Note that a queue created using a manager does not have this issue.
>   See [Programming guidelines.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-programming)

It might be worth trying to create your `Queue` object using `mp.Manager.Queue` and see if the issue goes away.